# How to put Visual Studio website project under source control and avoid absolute path problems?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio, I have opened a folder as a "website" project type. When leaving VS, it asked me to save the solution file which I did (to the same folder as my website). I have put everything into Git.

However, in the *.sln file, there are references to the folder name where my website resides, e.g. `Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\Website\"`. When some other team member checks out the files and uses a different top folder name the project fails to open.

Is this a limitation of VS project system or can I do something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure your project on disk so that the solution and website are in the same tree on disk (VS doesn't do this by default).  Something like:

```
OurSolution.sln
OurPrettyWebsite\
    Default.aspx
    web.config
```

Then everyone should clone the repository containing these files and the relative paths will always be the same (.\OurPrettyWebsite).

Comment: I like this suggestion. Although it creates an "unnecessary" sub-folder for the website, it's probably the best solution.

Comment: If it was a project (*.csproj) you can put them in the same folder, but VS doesn't always correctly handle the case where the .sln file is in the website root folder.

Answer (score 2):

For that we were using workaround.

All developers must have virtual disk W: and open all solutions/projects from that virtual disk.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to manually edit the *.sln file and change something like

```
Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\Website\"
```

to

```
Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "."
```

Visual Studio will work fine with this change.